# image Switcher is not working properly

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, runnable

i have an android application which should show Ads, those ads are pulled from server and then they are being saved on the phone,i made a method which should show ads but unfortunately,it's not working as expected it display the first image for a long time and then it loops over them too fast  i have no idea why
here is my method

```
private void startShowAds(final ArrayList<Ad> adArrayList) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    for (int i = 0; i < adArrayList.size(); i++) {
        Ad ad = adArrayList.get(i);
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {        
            public void run() {
                imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(getBitMap(ad.getFileUri()));
                handler.postDelayed(this, ad.getDuration());
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, ad.getDuration());
    }
    startShowAds(dbHelper.getAllAdRecords(longitude, latitude));
}
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: In the for loop you should fix the offsets for the delays. Also what's the point of the `i` inside the runnable?

Comment: edited Sorry i was by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void startShowAds(final ArrayList<Ad> adArrayList) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    long offset = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < adArrayList.size(); i++) {
        Ad ad = adArrayList.get(i);
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(getBitMap(ad.getFileUri()));;
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, offset);
        offset += ad.getDuration();
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds awesome it works perfect , i have a littel problem now how could i repeat this method for many times

Comment: outside the for loop you could add other runnable that calls  `startShowAds(adArrayList)` and start it with post delayed

Comment: so it can be done like this ?

`new Runnable(){public void run (){startShowAds(arrayList)}}` ?

Comment: Yes, and then do `handler.postDelayed(newRunnable, offset);`

Comment: sounds cool
well i just have 1 other question 
what   `offset += ad.getDuration();` does ?

Comment: It is the same as `offset = offset + ad.getDuration()`. It calculates when each ad should start to avoid overlapping them.

Comment: yes sure i understood that my question is why you use the offset  ? 
what if we do like this offset=ad.getDuration()

Comment: If you do that you will overlap the ads. You need to add the duration to each one to calculate the start of the next